# How to take results from twitter api and turn into DF

Tags: python, twitter

I want to count the total number of usernames that are returned in my results. Does anyone have an easy way to go about this? Should I turn everything into a df, and go from there? I have tried a ton of things, but have not been successful. thanks!

```
            import os
            import tweepy as tw
            import pandas as pd

            consumer_key = ""
            consumer_secret = ""
            access_token = ""
            access_token_secret = ""

            auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
            auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
            api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

            search_words = "test"
            date_since = "2020-06-24"

            # Collect tweets
            tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
            q=search_words,
            lang="en",
            since=date_since).items(5)

            # Iterate and print tweets
            for tweet in tweets:
            print(tweet.user.screen_name + ' ' + tweet.user.location)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want number of different usernames you can use Counter to get the number of occurrences in `tweets` (Python 2.7 and 3.x).

```
from collections import Counter
z = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b']
Counter(z)
```

```
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

If you are interested in number of all usernames just sum everything returned by `Couter`.